# c++ get process owner / current user token

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, token

I'm trying to get the current user token from a normal process (not elevated, not SYSTEM, etc). I've tried this using `WTSQueryUserToken`, but you need SYSTEM access for that so that won't work. And the only thing I find on the internet is getting the user SID or name but I couldn't find anything about getting the current user token. Is this even possible?

Comment: what you mean under "current" user ? from which process you try do this ?

Comment: `WTSQueryUserToken` is for retrieving the token belonging to the user logged into a particular session, nothing to do with a process.  If you want to retrieve the token associated with a process, use `OpenProcessToken`.

Comment: I want to get the user token from the user that run the program (the program should have access to the user token because it has been run by that user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want the token associated with the current process.  This is straightforward:

```
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, &token_handle)) fail();
```

Note that you may need to specify different permissions, depending on what you are intending to do with the token once you've got it.  The `TOKEN_READ` permission is appropriate if you are querying the token, e.g., to extract the username.  If you want to enable privileges, another common use for the current process token, you need `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGE` instead.

Comment: Is this returns CURRENT USER token? @Harry Johnston

Comment: @NarendraPrasath, the phrase "current user" is ambiguous.  This code returns the token for the user that the process is running as.  Whether that's the token you actually need depends on context.

Comment: can I impersonate logged on user using this token ? @Harry Johnston

Comment: @Narenda, only if the process is already running as the logged on user, in which case impersonation would not be necessary.

Comment: I am running a service program in that case it won't work i guess. What could be the other ways i can impersonate logged on user from my service program. @Harry Johnston

Comment: @Narenda, WTSQueryUserToken.  There are lots of existing questions about it; if you can't find one that addresses your particular problem, you can ask a new question.

Comment: [I asked same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147567/how-to-impersonate-logged-on-user-in-windows-service-c) @Harry Johnston